# Camunda stage-name change for previous versions

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

**Problem :**

- Is it possible to change any information pertaining to the stage-names in BPMN
   work-flow **for previous versions** 
  or do we need to deploy a new version for such minor changes?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure, what you mean by "stage names", but every change to the bpmn xml has to go through deployment to be available on the engine.
You don not have to manually create a new version, camunda will just create a new revision based on same key and version for you.